# Unit testing a retrofit call that uses kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm using [kotlin coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) and [kotlin retrofit coroutines](https://github.com/gildor/kotlin-coroutines-retrofit) to do network requests in the project I'm currently working on. But I'm unable to figure out how to make my unittests for the logic pass.

Here's my code:

```
class WorklistInteractor @Inject
    constructor(private val worklistRepository: WorklistRepository,
        private val preferenceManager: PreferenceManager)
: NetworkInteractor, WorklistDialogContract.Interactor {

    private var job = Job()

    override fun getWorklist(listener: OnWorklistResultListener) {
        job = launch(UI) {
            val result = async {
                worklistRepository.getWorklist(
                    ip = preferenceManager.worklistIp,
                    port = preferenceManager.worklistPort).awaitResult()
            }.await()

            when (result) {
            //Successful HTTP result
                is Result.Ok -> listener.onWorklistResult(result.value)
            // Any HTTP error
                is Result.Error -> {
                    Timber.e(result.exception, "HTTP error with code %s}", result.exception.code())
                    when(result.exception.code()) {
                        401 -> listener.onInvalidCredentialsFailure()
                        500 -> listener.internalServerError()
                        503 -> listener.noServerResponseFailure()
                        else -> listener.onError(result.exception.cause.toString())
                    }
                }
            // Exception while request invocation
                is Result.Exception -> {
                    Timber.e(result.exception.cause, "Exception with cause %s", result.exception.cause.toString())
                    when(result.exception) {
                        is ConnectException -> listener.connectionRefused()
                        is SocketTimeoutException -> listener.failedToConnectToHost()
                        else -> listener.onError(result.exception.cause.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun cancel() {
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

Here's one of my unittest:

```
@Test
fun `when worklistquery returns result, pass result back through listeners onWorklistResult`()
        = runBlocking {

    whenever(mWorklistRepositoryMock.getWorklist(anyString(), anyInt(), anyString()))
            .thenReturn(Calls.response(expectedWorklistResult))

    mInteractor.getWorklist(mOnWorklistResultListenerMock)

    verify(mOnWorklistResultListenerMock).onWorklistResult(expectedWorklistResult)
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(mOnWorklistResultListenerMock)
}
```

I keep getting the following message when run:

> Wanted but not invoked:
>   onWorklistResultListener.onWorklistResult(
>       
>   );
>   -> at com.example.dialogs.worklistdialog.WorklistInteractorTest$when worklistquery returns result, pass result back through listeners OnWorklistResult()$1.doResume(WorklistInteractorTest.kt:58)
>
> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Comment: I've tried running it as an Android instrumentation test with the AndroidJUnit4 runner also, but this doesn't work either

Comment: Changing launch(UI) to runBlocking makes the unittest pass!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to change the implementation quite heavily. Turns out that using the `launch` coroutine-builder from a regular function isn't that straight forward when it's not used from an Android Activity/Fragment.

Instead of using a regular function I changed the `getWorklist()` function to a suspending function and used `withContext` coroutine-builder. Here's the new implementation:

```
override suspend fun getWorklist(listener: OnWorklistResultListener) {
        withContext(CommonPool) {
            Timber.i("Loading worklist")
            val result = worklistRepository.getWorklist(
                    ip = preferenceManager.worklistIp,
                    port = preferenceManager.worklistPort,
                    aeTitle = preferenceManager.worklistAeTitle)
                    .awaitResult()
            when (result) {
            //Successful HTTP result
           ... left out for brevity (it's the same as before) ...
```

Now all the tests pass.

Answer (score 3):

You found solution, but maybe for other people, especially beginners, it might be helpful to explain why you were getting errors in the first place and why `runBlocking` helps. The issue is, that when running unit tests, the expectation is, that these tests are synchronous, that is, if any code is executed on some separate thread some time later, the test runner will never know about that, because for the test runner the test is finished when it's method call on the test runner's thread is finished.

Therefore it is impossible to test code not running on the main thread. In fact, it is even a bad practice trying to do that. Since there is no guarantee of when the code running on another thread will finish (if ever), we don't know what state the main thread will be in at the time (the main thread might not even exist anymore, as is the case with unit test runner).

Even if it were somehow possible to test code executed in other threads, every test run would inevitably be different (as a consequence of the above paragraph) and tests might produce different results on every run. That goes directly against the ideology of tests being reliable and yielding the same results on every single run.

Therefore when testing, all tested code needs to run on the main thread and one should make sure to never try call any asynchronous code in tests.

The `runBlocking` coroutine, unsurprisingly runs the code within it in blocking manner, on the thread it is launched from (as opposed to `launch`, that will cause the code to be run asynchronously).

There's one caveat to all this, that coroutines are not threads, but if you replace the word `thread` in the above text for `asynchronous coroutine`, the text will not lose any of its meaning. What I said is applicable for both when you're using traditional threads and also when you're using coroutines.

Comment: Just to clarify if you change the implementation to use runBlcoking you will get an ANR error.

Comment: that means, that you're trying to test some very complicated resource heavy computation... Maybe your mocks don't work the way you expect them to... From the test code you shared it's not obvious what part of code does the resource heavy computation. Are you per chance using real objects that try to write to database or read from database, or perform real network requests?

Comment: I'm performing a network request using retrofit. I've actually just found out that if I end my method with runBlocking { job?.join() } my tests all pass. But I'm having some trouble figuring out a solution to this. Could be related to [this issue](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/issues/205)

Comment: It doesn't sound related to me. I still think, that your issue is, that you're performing resource heavy calculations or real network calls in your tests and that's not correct. I suggest using debugger to see what is being called and what causes the ANR. It's most likely some network call or database read or something similar. You need to mock your network calls.

One more thing, I don't see you use `await()` in your test code wrapped inside `runBlocking` and that might as well be the issue. Coroutine expects that somehow finish the job, `await()` is one such way. The test looks incorrect.